# Babel with Hebrew and Listings Conflicts: Makes the Listings Look Weird

Tags: listings, babel

When I use the babel package for Hebrew support, framed listings in the document look weird, same for listings with background color.

Any idea how to solve?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\section*{First Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
this
is
a 
simple
listing
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Second Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
this
is
a 
simple
listing with frame
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Third Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{red}]
this
is
a 
simple
listing with background color
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Forth Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,backgroundcolor=\color{red}]
this
is
a 
simple
listing with frame and background color
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hebrew changes `\everypar` and listings doesn't like this. You can reset the original definition at the begin of the listing:

Side-remark: you can make better frames and backgrounds with tcolorbox.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}{\let\everypar\o@everypar }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section*{First Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
this
is
a
simple
listing
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Second Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
this
is
a
simple
listing with frame
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Third Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{red}]
this
is
a
simple
listing with background color
\end{lstlisting}

\section*{Forth Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,backgroundcolor=\color{red}]
this
is
a
simple
listing with frame and background color
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @UlrikeFischery our answer solved by problem, thanks!
(will look into tcolorbox)